# sp::over(). Does the dot belong to one of the polygons identified with an OGRGeoJSON file?

Tags: r, geojson, spatial, r-sp, ogr

I'm trying to get a boolleans vector, where for example, v[i] =1 tells me if an i-th point (latitude longitude pair, present inside a *train* dataframe) falls within one of the geographical areas identified by an OGRGeoJSON file.

The [OGR file](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm) is structured roughly like this:

- District 1: 24 polygonal
- District 2: 4  polygonal
- District 3: 27 polygonal
- District 4: 18 polygonal
- District 5: 34 polygonal

That's what I tried to do.

However, the results obtained **are not correct** because the polygonal that is generated is a mix of all the various areas present in the OGR file.

```
library(rgdal)
library(httr)
library(sp)

r <- GET('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/geospatial/tqmj-j8zm?method=export&format=GeoJSON')
nyc_neighborhoods <- readOGR(content(r,'text'), 'OGRGeoJSON', verbose = F)

#New York City polygonal
pol_lat <- c(nyc_neighborhoods_df$lat)
pol_long <- c(nyc_neighborhoods_df$long)
xy <- cbind(pol_lat, pol_long)
p = Polygon(xy)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
pol = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))

#Points to analyse (pair of coordinates)
ny_lat <- c(train$pickup_latitude, train$dropoff_latitude)
ny_long <- c(train$pickup_longitude, train$dropoff_longitude)
ny_coord <- cbind(ny_lat, ny_long)
pts <- SpatialPoints(ny_coord)

#Query: Does the point to analyze fall in or out NYC?
over(pts, pol, returnList = TRUE)
```

How can I fix this to get the correct result?

Comment: can you add `dput(nyc_neighborhoods_df)`

Comment: @dww, I think that `nyc_neighborhoods_df` is `nyc_neighborhoods`, and they just renamed objects at some point and didn't finish the job. @pofferbacco, can you provide the output for `head(train)`? Or describe where we can find this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp` is an older package which is being phased out in favor of the newer "Simple Features" `sf` package. Let me know if you are open to using the pipe operator `%>%` from the `magrittr` package, as it works nicely with the `sf` package (as does `dplyr` and `purrr`).

Using `sf`, you could do:

```r
library(sf)

# Replace this with the path to the geojson file
geojson_path <- "path/to/file.geojson"

boroughs <- sf::st_read(dsn = geojson_path, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now making a very simple spatial point object to stand in for the "trains" data.

```r
# Make test data.frame

test_df <- 
  data.frame(
  # Random test point I chose, a couple of blocks from Central Park
      a = "manhattan_point", 
      y = 40.771959, 
      x = -73.964128, 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Turn the test_df into a spatial object
test_point <-
  sf::st_as_sf(
    test_df,
    # The coords argument tells the st_as_sf function
    # what columns store the longitude and latitude data
    # which it uses to associate a spatial point to each
    # row in the data.frame
    coords = c("x", "y"), 
    crs = 4326 # WGS84
    )
```

Now we are ready to determine what polygon(s) our point falls in:

```
# Get the sparse binary predicate. This will give a list with as 
# many elements as there are spatial objects in the first argument, 
# in this case, test_point, which has 1 element.
# It also has attributes which detail what the relationship is
# (intersection, in our case) 
sparse_bin_pred <- sf::st_intersects(test_point, boroughs)

# Output the boro_name that matched. I think the package purrr
# offers some more intuitive ways to do this, but
lapply(
  sparse_bin_pred, 
  function(x) boroughs$boro_name[x]
  )
```

That last part outputs:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Manhattan"
```

Comment: from memory `sf::st_join(..., left = FALSE )` will give you a direct inner-join of points in the polygons, so no need for the `lapply` at the end.

Comment: it worked great!
I just started with R, and I didn't know the sf library. Definitely much faster than sp. Thanks for the help, I'd offer you a beer more than gladly!